# Capture div containing inline svg and download it as image

Tags: jquery, angularjs, reactjs, ember.js, aurelia

I wrote code to capture a screenshot of a page using html5. Everything is fine except when the page contains an svg. When I convert svg to inline svg after that screenshot is not capturing the inline svg.

Please check https://jsfiddle.net/7bqukhff/4/

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/download/0.5.0-alpha1/html2canvas.svg.js"></script>
<script src="https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/releases/download/0.5.0-alpha1/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
   <h1>Scrrenshot</h1>
   <div class="img-div"><img src='https://istack.000webhostapp.com/1tf.svg'></div>
   <form class="cf">
      <div class="half left cf">
         <input type="text" id="input-name" placeholder="Name">
         <input type="email" id="input-email" placeholder="Email address">
         <input type="text" id="input-subject" placeholder="Subject">
      </div>
      <div class="half right cf">
         <textarea name="message" type="text" id="input-message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="input-submit">
   </form>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-success" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="generate();">Generate Screenshot »</a>

$(function() {

   $('img').each(function() {

      var $img = jQuery(this);
      var imgID = $img.attr('id');
      var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
      var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

      jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
         // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
         var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

         // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
         if (typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
         }
         // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
         if (typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass + ' replaced-svg');
         }
         // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
         $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

         // Replace image with new SVG
         $img.replaceWith($svg);

      }, 'xml');

   });
});

(function(exports) {
   function urlsToAbsolute(nodeList) {
      if (!nodeList.length) {
         return [];
      }
      var attrName = 'href';
      if (nodeList[0].__proto__ === HTMLImageElement.prototype || nodeList[0].__proto__ === HTMLScriptElement.prototype) {
         attrName = 'src';
      }
      nodeList = [].map.call(nodeList, function(el, i) {
         var attr = el.getAttribute(attrName);
         if (!attr) {
            return;
         }
         var absURL = /^(https?|data):/i.test(attr);
         if (absURL) {
            return el;
         } else {
            return el;
         }
      });
      return nodeList;
   }

   function screenshotPage() {
      var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
      html2canvas(wrapper, {
         onrendered: function(canvas) {
            canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
               saveAs(blob, 'myScreenshot.png');
            });
         }
      });
   }

   function addOnPageLoad_() {
      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
         var scrollX = document.documentElement.dataset.scrollX || 0;
         var scrollY = document.documentElement.dataset.scrollY || 0;
         window.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
      });
   }

   function generate() {
      screenshotPage();
   }
   exports.screenshotPage = screenshotPage;
   exports.generate = generate;
})(window);
```

For this particular svg there is no problem, but for some svg the captured image is different from the original.

Is there any method for capturing a screenshot without using html canvas? If not how can I change my code to capture svg elements correctly?

I think now everyone is familiar with awesome screen shot extension https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/. How are they doing this screen capture?

Is there any method in Angular 1 (not 2 or above), React JS , Vue.js, Aurelia js or any modern JavaScript library for taking a screenshot?

Comment: If you have a canvas element -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

if you want to take a div's snapshot ->https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: currently i am using html2canvas , but it has some known problems .

Comment: Well we have an avatar system for creating and saving one but i also using html2canvas. It's just okey for me use for now. if i have a better solution ill write it down here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using a JavaScript library called [**canvg**](https://github.com/canvg/canvg) ( for rendering SVG on canvas properly ) , along with [**html2canvas**](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) .

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ**

```js
$(function() {

   $('img').each(function() {

      var $img = jQuery(this);
      var imgID = $img.attr('id');
      var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
      var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

      jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
         // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
         var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

         // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
         if (typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
         }
         // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
         if (typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
            $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass + ' replaced-svg');
         }
         // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
         $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

         // Replace image with new SVG
         $img.replaceWith($svg);

      }, 'xml');

   });
});

(function(exports) {
   function urlsToAbsolute(nodeList) {
      if (!nodeList.length) {
         return [];
      }
      var attrName = 'href';
      if (nodeList[0].__proto__ === HTMLImageElement.prototype || nodeList[0].__proto__ === HTMLScriptElement.prototype) {
         attrName = 'src';
      }
      nodeList = [].map.call(nodeList, function(el, i) {
         var attr = el.getAttribute(attrName);
         if (!attr) {
            return;
         }
         var absURL = /^(https?|data):/i.test(attr);
         if (absURL) {
            return el;
         } else {
            return el;
         }
      });
      return nodeList;
   }

   function screenshotPage() {
      var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
      html2canvas(wrapper, {
         onrendered: function(canvas) {
            function getOffset(el) {
               el = el.getBoundingClientRect();
               return {
                  left: el.left + window.scrollX,
                  top: el.top + window.scrollY
               }
            }
            var cachedCanvas = canvas;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            var svgs = document.querySelectorAll('svg');
            svgs.forEach(function(svg) {
               var svgWidth = svg.width.baseVal.value;
               var svgHeight = svg.height.baseVal.value;
               var svgLeft = getOffset(svg).left - 40;
               var svgTop = getOffset(svg).top - 62;
               var offScreenCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
               offScreenCanvas.width = svgWidth;
               offScreenCanvas.height = svgHeight;
               canvg(offScreenCanvas, svg.outerHTML);
               ctx.drawImage(cachedCanvas, 0, 0);
               ctx.drawImage(offScreenCanvas, svgLeft, svgTop);
            });
            canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
               saveAs(blob, 'myScreenshot.png');
            });
         }
      });
   }

   function addOnPageLoad_() {
      window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(e) {
         var scrollX = document.documentElement.dataset.scrollX || 0;
         var scrollY = document.documentElement.dataset.scrollY || 0;
         window.scrollTo(scrollX, scrollY);
      });
   }

   function generate() {
      screenshotPage();
   }
   exports.screenshotPage = screenshotPage;
   exports.generate = generate;
})(window);
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather);
$red: #e74c3c;
*,
*:before,
*:after {
   @include box-sizing(border-box);
}

html,
body {
   background: #f1f1f1;
   font-family: 'Merriweather', sans-serif;
   padding: 1em;
}

h1 {
   text-align: center;
   color: #a8a8a8;
   @include text-shadow(1px 1px 0 rgba(white, 1));
}

form {
   border: 2px solid blue;
   margin: 20px auto;
   max-width: 600px;
   padding: 5px;
   text-align: center;
}

input,
textarea {
   border: 0;
   outline: 0;
   padding: 1em;
   @include border-radius(8px);
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   margin-top: 1em;
   font-family: 'Merriweather', sans-serif;
   @include box-shadow(0 1px 1px rgba(black, 0.1));
   resize: none;
   &:focus {
      @include box-shadow(0 0px 2px rgba($red, 1)!important);
   }
}

#input-submit {
   color: white;
   background: $red;
   cursor: pointer;
   &:hover {
      @include box-shadow(0 1px 1px 1px rgba(#aaa, 0.6));
   }
}

textarea {
   height: 126px;
}


}
.half {
   float: left;
   width: 48%;
   margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.right {
   width: 50%;
}
.left {
   margin-right: 2%;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
   .half {
      width: 100%;
      float: none;
      margin-bottom: 0;
   }
}

/* Clearfix */
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
   content: " ";
   /* 1 */
   
   display: table;
   /* 2 */
}
.cf:after {
   clear: both;
}
.half.left.cf > input {
   margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/canvg@2.0.0-beta.1/dist/browser/canvg.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
   <h1>Scrrenshot</h1>
   <div class="img-div">
      <img src='https://istack.000webhostapp.com/1tf.svg'>
   </div>
   <form class="cf">
      <div class="half left cf">
         <input type="text" id="input-name" placeholder="Name">
         <input type="email" id="input-email" placeholder="Email address">
         <input type="text" id="input-subject" placeholder="Subject">
      </div>
      <div class="half right cf">
         <textarea name="message" type="text" id="input-message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="input-submit">
   </form>
</div>
<a class="btn btn-success" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="generate();">Generate Screenshot »</a>
```

Comment: var svgLeft = getOffset(svg).left - 40;
var svgTop = getOffset(svg).top - 62; why this two line?

Comment: to get svg element's top and left position on the page

Comment: but from where this 40 and 62 come ? We can not make it dynamic?

Comment: for the above example its seems that you need to subtract those values from the original position to set the correct alignment for svg on the canvas. but in other cases you can exclude those values if you wish and if the svg correctly aligns on the canvas